# Nothing of openGL works in my code. Identifier "GL_MODELVIEW" is undefined. 284

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

Below is a code for dynamic sort and I am not able to find out what is wrong with it and all the glut packages are installed, the GL codes are not working
the error throws-

> *Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error (active)    E0018   expected a
> ')'   Project2    C:\Users\rando\source\repos\Project2\Source.cpp 282
> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State*
> *Error (active)   E0020   identifier "glBegin" is undefined   Project2    C:\Users\rando\source\repos\Project2\Source.cpp 77*

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<glut.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

#define MAX 10
int k = 0;
typedef struct circle
{
   GLfloat x;  //x axis of center
   GLfloat y;  //y axis of center
   GLfloat r;  // radius
}circle;

circle c[MAX];  //array of circles to store the center and radius of each circle
int a[MAX];     // int array for sorting algo
int initial[MAX] = { 10,4,8,6,3,7,9,1,5,2 };    //int array to restore random values after sorting
GLfloat initial_x1, initial_x2; //to set the destiniation for swapping

int global_i = 0, global_j = 0; //i and j values for bubble-sort
int swapping = 0;   //flag to check if circle are being swapped
int sorting = 0;    //start sorting only after user input

void initialise()
{
   global_i = global_j = swapping = 0; //reset all globals
   for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
   {
       a[i] = initial[i];  //if a[] is sorted restore from initial[] 
       c[i].r = a[i] * 4.0;    //4 because to fit 10 circles in screen
       c[i].y = 300.0;     //vertical center of window
       if (i == 0)
           c[i].x = 45.0;  // first circle starts from 45 offset
       else
           c[i].x = c[i - 1].x + 90.0;//(c[i-1].r+c[i].r+10.0); //distance between circles = sum of 2 max readii
       printf("%f - %f - %f\n", c[i].x, c[i].y, c[i].r); //for testing purpose don worry
   }
}

//func to display text on screen char by char
void bitmap_output(int x, int y, const char* string, void* font)
{
   int len, i;

   glRasterPos2f(x, y);
   len = (int)strlen(string);
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
       glutBitmapCharacter(font, string[i]);
   }
}

//function to integer to string
void int_str(int rad, char r[])
{
   switch (rad)
   {
   case 1: strcpy(r, "1"); break;
   case 2: strcpy(r, "2"); break;
   case 3: strcpy(r, "3"); break;
   case 4: strcpy(r, "4"); break;
   case 5: strcpy(r, "5"); break;
   case 6: strcpy(r, "6"); break;
   case 7: strcpy(r, "7"); break;
   case 8: strcpy(r, "8"); break;
   case 9: strcpy(r, "9"); break;
   case 10: strcpy(r, "10"); break;
   }

}

//draw circle by drawing consecutive triangle fans
void circle_draw(circle c)
{
   float i;
   glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
   glVertex2f(c.x, c.y);   //center of circle
   for (i = 0; i < 360; i += 1)
       glVertex2f(c.x + sin(i) * c.r, c.y + cos(i) * c.r);
   glEnd();

   //display the value of circle below
   int x = c.x - 2;
   int y = c.y - (c.r + 10);
   int rad = c.r / 4;
   char r[3] = "";
   int_str(rad, r);
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   bitmap_output(x, y, r, GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_10);

}

// swaps circles cc1 and cc2 by changing their centers
void swap_circles(circle* cc1, circle* cc2)
{
   if (swapping == 0)  //if circles are not being swapped set destination for each circles
   {
       initial_x1 = cc1->x; //center of circle in left
       initial_x2 = cc2->x; //center of circle in right
       swapping = 1;   //means cicle are being swapped
       printf("%f - %f\n", cc1->r, cc2->r);

   }

   if (initial_x1 <= cc2->x)   //decrease the center of circle in right till its > center of left circle
       cc2->x -= 1.0;      //speed of animation

   if (initial_x2 >= cc1->x)//increase the center of circle in left till its < center of right circle
       cc1->x += 1.0;

   printf("one %f - %f\n", initial_x1, cc2->x);
   printf("two %f - %f\n", initial_x2, cc1->x);

   // if difference between destination and center < 0.3 then cicles are swapped
   if (abs(initial_x1 - cc2->x) < 0.3 && abs(initial_x2 - cc1->x) < 0.3)  //set this to speed of animation
   {
       swapping = 0;

       int temp = cc1->x;
       cc1->x = cc2->x;
       cc2->x = temp;

       temp = cc1->y;
       cc1->y = cc2->y;
       cc2->y = temp;

       temp = cc1->r;
       cc1->r = cc2->r;
       cc2->r = temp;
   }

}


void sort() //bubble sort algo
{
   if (!swapping) //if not in process of swappin 2 circles only then get 2 new circles to swap
   {
       while (global_i < 10)
       {
           global_j = global_i;
           while (global_j < 9)
           {
               if (a[global_j] > a[global_j + 1])
               {
                   printf("%d %d\n", global_j, a[global_j]);
                   int temp = a[global_j];
                   a[global_j] = a[global_j + 1];
                   a[global_j + 1] = temp;
                   goto SWAP;

               }
               global_j++;
           }
           global_i++;
       }
   }
SWAP:
   printf("swapping --> %d - %d\n", global_j, global_j + 1);
   bitmap_output(10, 375, "Swapping ->", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);

   char r[3] = "";
   int_str(a[global_j], r);
   bitmap_output(150, 375, r, GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
   int_str(a[global_j + 1], r);
   bitmap_output(175, 375, r, GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);

   swap_circles(&c[global_j], &c[global_j + 1]);
}

void display_text()
{
   bitmap_output(200, 565, "DYNAMIC SORTING ALGORITHM VISUALISER", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);//title larger font
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP); //to underline the title
   glVertex2f(180, 560);
   glVertex2f(750, 560);
   glEnd();

   //other text small font
   bitmap_output(10, 525, "This program sorts a random set of numbers in ascending order displaying them graphically as ", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
   bitmap_output(10, 505, "circles with varying radii.", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);


   if (sorting == 0)//if not sorting display menu
   {
       bitmap_output(10, 455, "MENU", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
       bitmap_output(10, 435, "Press s to SORT", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
       bitmap_output(10, 415, "Press r to RANDOMISE", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
       bitmap_output(10, 395, "Esc to QUIT", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
   }
   else if (sorting == 1)
   {
       glColor3f(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
       bitmap_output(10, 455, "Sorting in progress...", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
       bitmap_output(10, 435, "Please do not quit", GLUT_BITMAP_9_BY_15);
       glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   }

}

void front()
{
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
   bitmap_output(390, 565, "WELCOME!", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
   glVertex2f(388, 560);
   glVertex2f(524, 560);
   glEnd();
   bitmap_output(440, 535, "TO", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
   glVertex2f(438, 531);
   glVertex2f(475, 531);
   glEnd();

   bitmap_output(200, 495, "DYNAMIC SORTING ALGORITHM VISUALISER", GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24);
   glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);
   glVertex2f(198, 490);
   glVertex2f(731, 490);
   glEnd();
   glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
   glBegin(GL_QUADS);
   glVertex2f(594, 120.0); glVertex2f(594, 145); glVertex2f(836, 145); glVertex2f(836, 120.0);
   glEnd();
   glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   bitmap_output(600, 125, "Press Enter to continue.......", GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18);

}

void display(void)
{
   glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
   glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

   if (k == 0)
       front();
   else
   {

       display_text();

       glPointSize(2.0);
       for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
       {
           glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
           circle_draw(c[i]);
       }
       if (global_j + 1 < MAX && sorting == 1) // call sort only on key press
           sort();
       else
           sorting = 0;
   }

   glFlush();
   glutSwapBuffers();

}

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
   if (key == 13)
       k = 1;
   if (k == 1)
   {
       switch (key)
       {
       case 27: exit(0); //27 is the ascii code for the ESC key
       case 's': sorting = 1; break;
       case 'r': initialise(); break;
       }
   }
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
   glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   glLoadIdentity();
   if (w <= h)
       glOrtho(-2.0, 2.0, -2.0 * (GLfloat)h / (GLfloat)w, 2.0 * (GLfloat)h / (GLfloat)w, -10.0, 10.0);
   else
       glOrtho(-2.0 * (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, 2.0 * (GLfloat)w / (GLfloat)h, -2.0, 2.0, -10.0, 10.0);

   glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

void init(void)
{
   glClearColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
   gluOrtho2D(0.0, 900.0, 0.0, 600.0);
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   glutInit(&argc, argv);
   glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50);
   glutInitWindowSize(900, 600);
   glutCreateWindow("Dynamic Sorting Algorithm Visualiser");
   init();
   initialise();
   glutDisplayFunc(display);
   glutIdleFunc(display);
   glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
   glutMainLoop();
}```
````

Comment: glut != OpenGL. You need to include the OpenGL header and to linke the opengl library respectively loader.

Comment: of course why dint that strike my head ,thanks